# Create method using String. C#

Tags: c#, string, methods

I was trying to create a method which would produce "Adam" in the MessageBox with the title "The Title". This code is not working. Is this because return can only return one value e.g. string name only? If I delete the title option it works fine. Any ideas would be great.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(myMethod("Adam", "The Title"));
    }
    string myMethod(string name, string title)
    {
        return name, title;             
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You have to return one object of type string. so you have to return name + title.

Comment: `return string.Concat(name,title);` or `return name + title;`

Comment: Why do you want one method for setting both the text and the title? A method can only return one instance (one data type). Either use two methods for producing Title and Message or invoke the `MessageBox.Show` directly from your method. Please explain further what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi, OK no problem. I thought that might be the case. When I use void instead of string I can produce a method that has both the name in the MessageBox and the title of the MessageBox. I think I am getting confused how I can have two values with void but only one with string. private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myMethod("Adam", "The Title");
        }
        void myMethod(string name, string title)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(name,title);             
        }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(myMethod("Adam", "The Title"));
    }
    string myMethod(string name, string title)
    {
        return name + " " + title;             
    }
```

**EDIT: To Show "The Title" on the texbox**

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           myMethod("Adam", "The Title");
        }
        void myMethod(string name, string title)
        {
             MessageBox.Show(name,title);       
        }
```

Comment: The title should probably be the second argument to the Show method, since the OP says he wants the Title to be "The Title". But the question is rather confusing.

Comment: Agree, it doesn't matter the idea is that he is using a wrong return

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. This produces the name and the title in the MessageBox, which is useful as I needed to know how to do that as well. Sorry I am new to programming as I am sure you have guessed. I was trying to have the name "Adam" in the MessageBox with the title of the MessageBox "The Title." Any ideas?

Comment: Check my edit, maybe it's what you need. THe Title on the Textbox Caption

Comment: Hi, cheers for the suggestion. This code does not run unless you change string to void, which is how I was doing it originally. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Yes of course, I forgot to change the function to method but the code works. Already changed I copy/pasted from the previous one to avoid re-typing

Answer (score 0):

A method can only return one value. The value returned can be of a complex type, so you could return multiple strings by creating your own data type (or using a built in type):

```
class Message
{
   public string Title {get; set;}
   public string Message {get; set;}
}
```

Using this you can do

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var message = MyMethod("Title", "Message");
    MessageBox.Show(message.Title, message.Message);
}

Message myMethod(string name, string title)
{
    return new Message{Title = title, Message = name};             
}
```

Given this scenario it's pretty pointless, but `myMethod` could do a lookup or manipulation of the arguments, to produce the returned message.

Another way is, as already discussed here, to let `myMethod` handle the display of the message box.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myMethod("Adam", "The Title");
}
void myMethod(string name, string title)
{
    MessageBox.Show(name,title);       
}
```